# Store several elements on a variable

Tags: javascript

I have created a styling reset as the first part of a form validation. I must clear two types of elements: inputs and select. Can I store on a variable two kinds of elements? So that `inputs` var stores both inputs and select objects.

```
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var totalInputs= inputs .length;

  for (var i = 0; i < totalInputs; i++){
        inputs[i].removeAttribute("style");;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store multiple elements in the single variable by using `querySelectorAll` only. But not by using `getElementsByTagName`.

Here you can store both `input` and `select` objects by,

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input,select");
```

Check this example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input,select");
    var totalInputs = inputs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalInputs; i++) {
      inputs[i].removeAttribute("style");;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="background:#b6ff00" />
<select style="background:#b6ff00">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<button>Remove</button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Very grateful. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByTagName` returns a node list. I would suggest using `querySelectorAll` to get the input and select elements.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input,select"));
var totalInputs = inputs.length;

for (var i = 0; i < totalInputs; i++){
    inputs[i].removeAttribute("style");;
}
```

Comment: `.concat` is an array method, while you have a NodeList.

Comment: I understand, thank yout. But for some reason, your code makes the application fail on sumitting, there's some mistake on it (not the double dot comma after ("style");;

Comment: @Scimonster Yup I just realized that. I will update.